# more recent build of GNU coreutils for win32?

Tags: windows, unix, coreutils

Is there a more recent build of unxutils.zip? (The unix command-line utilities for Windows) The canonical downloads are at http://unxutils.sourceforge.net/ but they date from 1999-2003; in particular the `du.exe` does not contain the [`--max-depth`](http://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/du-invocation.html) argument.

[GNUWin32 Coreutils](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/coreutils.htm) is a little more recent but dates to 2005 (version 5.3.0) and doesn't have the `du --max-depth` argument either.

Comment: If you need only `du` then perhaps [Microsoft's version](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896651.aspx) can be used instead?

Comment: thx, already using it, but that doesn't solve the problem

Comment: "doesn't solve the problem" in what way exactly? Anyway if you don't find a pre-compiled Windows binary from somewhere I guess you'll just have to compile it yourself.

Answer (score 18):

Seems Git for Windows comes with current builds!

http://git-scm.com/download/win

After installation, have a look at C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin.

Comment: Unfortunately they are the msys versions that depends on having the msys-*.dll's available.

Comment: I found my Git installation in my user's AppData directory, specifically: `C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Local\Programs\Git\usr\bin`
 
I added my version of the above to my PATH environment variable and then my GNU withdrawal pains eased.

Answer (score 6):

A newer version of coreutils for Windows can also be obtained using [msys2](https://www.msys2.org/).
Currently, the version of coreutils is 8.31:
https://packages.msys2.org/base/coreutils

Answer (score 5):

https://github.com/uutils/coreutils/
**uutils** is an attempt at writing universal (as in cross-platform) CLI utilities in Rust.

> ```
> coreutils-0.0.16-aarch64-unknown-linux-gnu.tar.gz
> coreutils-0.0.16-arm-unknown-linux-gnueabihf.tar.gz
> coreutils-0.0.16-i686-pc-windows-msvc.zip
> coreutils-0.0.16-i686-unknown-linux-gnu.tar.gz
> coreutils-0.0.16-i686-unknown-linux-musl.tar.gz
> coreutils-0.0.16-x86_64-apple-darwin.tar.gz
> coreutils-0.0.16-x86_64-pc-windows-gnu.zip
> coreutils-0.0.16-x86_64-pc-windows-msvc.zip
> coreutils-0.0.16-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu.tar.gz
> coreutils-0.0.16-x86_64-unknown-linux-musl.tar.gz
> ```

Comment: interesting... but are there prebuilt binaries? if not, i'm not interested

Comment: @jason-s Yes, all the above listed files are prebuilt binaries for each platform. I'm using their windows binaries. So far so good.

Comment: even newer versions are available, e.g. https://github.com/uutils/coreutils/releases/tag/0.0.20

Comment: avaliable for win32 CLI :  eza, fd, riprep, tealdeer

Comment: scoop install uutils-coreutils